# Continuity via sequences in general topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have anexo exercise to answer that if for every sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ we have $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$ than is f continuous or not.
Continuous here means that $f^-1(A)$ is open If $A$ is open
I feel that this is false but can neither proof or show a counter example
PS: Sorry If duplicate but couldnt find the same question on search

Comment: Do you know about uncountable ordinals?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown never heard of but can look It up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can only guarantee that a function $f:X \to Y$ is continuous $\iff$ for every sequence $x_n$ in $X$ converging to $x \in X$ we have that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$ if $X$ is a so called $\textit{first countable}$ space.  If $X$ is not first countable, then one cannot guarantee that the latter implies the former.  A first countable space is a topological space $X$ where every $x \in X$ has a countable [neighbourhood basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system#Basis).   In the comment by $\textit{Cheerful Parsnip}$ there is a link to a nice counterexample showing this.